# Кульбаба. Чи є відмінності між синонімами залежно від стадії цвітіння/дозрівання рослини?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

СУМ-11 дає таке визачення [КУЛЬБА́БА](http://sum.in.ua/s/kuljbaba), и, жін.

> **КУЛЬБА́БА**, и, жін. **Трав'яниста рослина родини складноцвітих, стебло якої виділяє молочний сік, а пухнасте насіння розноситься
>   вітром.** *Зелений острів заквітчався рясними жовтими квітками
>   кульбаби, неначе хто посіяв по траві зорі* (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956,
>   129); *Обабіч степової дороги вітер оббивав пухнасті голівки кульбаби,
>   розкидав невагоме насіння, мов білий лебединий пух* (Микола Руденко,
>   Вітер.., 1958, 412); *На війні найзлісніший ворог той, що личкується в
>   одежу свого супротивника. Отак і кульбаба — все в ній схоже на
>   кок-сагиз — і корінь, і листя, і цвіт, і насіння* (Іван І. Волошин,
>   Сади.., 1950, 137);
>
> //  **Квітка цієї рослини**. *Одцвілись кульбаби у гаю, Облітають, мов
>   пороша біла* (Іван Нехода, Чудесний сад, 1962, 105).

Наведені приклади свідчать, що **кульбаба** вживається і на позначення *суцвіття* (жовтої головки), і на позначення *плоду* (білої пухнастої головки).

У статті у Вікіпедії [Кульбаба лікарська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0#cite_note-:0-3) стверджується, що

> В українській мові ***кульбаба*** відома під понад двома десятками
>   синонімів: ***купава***, ***пустодуй***, ***солдатики***,
>   ***літючки***, ***летючки***, ***бабакуля***, ***падиволос***, ***плішивець***, ***дикий молочай (молочій)***, ***молочник***, ***баранки***, ***бабка***, ***бабки***, ***вовчий зуб***, ***подойнички***, ***чичик***, ***чічак***, ***чічик***, ***малайниця***, ***мелайниця***, ***маївка***, ***пухлянки***, ***пушки***.

Ряд синонімів зазначається у статті [Л. А. МОСКАЛЕНКО "БОТАНІЧНІ ПАРАЛЕЛІ"](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine39-17.pdf):

> Напр.: «***кульбаба звичайна***» має такі назви: ***бабакуль***,
>   ***бабка***, ***діди***, ***жовте молочко***, ***кульбаба***, ***летючки***, ***молочій***, ***москалі (москалики)***, ***одуванчи(і)ки***, ***пустодуй***, ***пухлянки***, ***пуховник***, ***пушок***, ***фонарики***. Кожна з цих назв семантично прозора і зрозуміла для носіїв тієї чи іншої говірки. Деякі
>   з них функціонують паралельно без будь-якої семантико- стилістичної
>   диференціації.

У збірнику [Сестрички–україночки (вибрані твори)](http://evrika.if.ua/282/) Ігоря Гаврилюка є загадка:

> Парашути, парашути!
>   Вище яблуні і граба.
>   Рясно землю засіває
>   пустодуйками (кульбаба).

з якої, як на мене, зрозуміло, що ***пустодуйки*** - це вже білі головки, а не жовті квітки.

На більшість із зазначених синонімів немає статей у СУМ-11, а на деякі, наприклад ***купава***, ***падиволос***, ***маївка***, немає значення, яке б мало відношення до *кульбаби*.

**Отже, чи є все ж бодай якась відмінність між синонімами до слова *кульбаба* залежно від стадії дозрівання рослини, чи це тільки мої припущення?**

Answer (score 1):

У збірнику Василя Стуса (**Василь Стус. Вибрані твори.** Видання друге. Київ, "Смолоскип", 2014, с. 74), а також на [цьому ресурсі](http://ukr-lit.net/stus/270-virshi/177-ty-chervono-nikoly-ne-gorila.html), знайшла поезію **"Ти червоно ніколи не горіла"**. Поет вживає **`пізня кульбаба`**. Як на мене, досить вдало - не калькується з російської `одуванчик`, утім, зрозуміло, що йдеться про рослину саме в стадії дозрівання, а не цвітіння.

---

(Ти червоно ніколи не горіла,

О пізня кульбабо! Голівка посивіла

Хитається дрімотно у півсні —

Краси останній слід. Так само навесні

Ти піднімалася, в замріянні зростала,

Ти красувалася в пишноті молодій...)

Тремтить нитками порваних надій

Прозоре павутиння... Хвиле, стій!

Answer (score 0):

Гадаю, що те, як цю рослину називають, перш за все буде залежати від регіону. От, наприклад, у запитані йдеться, що "кульбабу" називають "молочаєм" - це справді так, в моєму містечку я не раз це чув, однак в цьому випадку йдеться не про саму квітку, а про її листочки (довгі, трикутної форми). Підтвердження того, що цю рослину так називають я знайшов [тут](http://proridne.net/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0.html), а також серед варіантів: "подуйчик", "сліпота".

І я не впевнений, але гадаю, що назва "подуйчик", а також "пустодуйки", "летючки", "солдатики" (напевно, ця назва появилася разом із десантними військами), "падиволос" тощо вживаються до плоду кульбаби, а не до квітки.

Однак, вважати кульбабу молочаєм - це не правильно, бо це різні родини рослин ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9) та ще одне [джерело](http://sadukr.ru/roslini/2746-kulbaba-ce-molochaj-chi-ni.html)), однак проаналізувавши сторінки в Інтернеті, а також враховуючи те, що я знаю багатьох людей, які так кажуть, я виявив, що це дуже поширена помилка (яка, напевно, було спричинена тим, що обидві рослини виділяють молочний сік). Те саме стосується "молочія", "молочника" та інших схожих слів.

Дивлячись на слово "купава", я подумав, що воно, напевно, пов'язане із святом Івана Купали, тому почав шукати [інформацію](https://ukr.media/culture/311712/) і дізнався, що ця рослина використовується як для ворожіння (тільки та, у якої сім'янки дозріли) та для вплетіння у [вінок](https://maximum.fm/nich-na-ivana-kupala-shcho-mozhna-robiti-i-shcho-ne-mozhna_n144112) (гадаю, що тут радше використовувалися жовті квіти кульбаби). Однак, пізніше я загуглив слово "купава" і побачив, що це звичайне "[латаття](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F))" (ще одна стаття із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5)). Досить складно припустити звідки взялася ця помилка, можливо, вінки із кульбаби, коли були спущені на воду, нагадували людям ту саму купаву (квітка якої теж може бути жовтою). Або ж, люди плутали її із [Купальницею](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) (яку також називають "[купава](http://at-its.com/cvety-v-sadu/6407-kupalnicja-kupava-trollius.html)"), хоч різниця, як на мене, очевидна.

Чічак - це з татарської квітка (тат. Чәчәк - [джерело](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BA)), напевно, так називали цю квітку монголо-татарські загарбники, а в деяких регіонах назва могла залишитися серед народу, гадаю, що може вживатися як і до квітки, так і до плоду кульбаби.

Також зрозуміло, чому плоди кульбаб називають "бабусями" - сива головка кульбаби асоціюється із сивою головою старої людини. А от чому їх називали "москалями" мені так і не вдалося зрозуміти.

Отож, гадаю, що назва кульбаби може залежати від періоду її цвітіння, бо було б не зовсім логічно називати жовту квітку "пустодуйкою" чи "пуховиком". Проте, варто враховувати, що деякі з синонімів можуть ввести в оману, тому варто їх або уникати, або зробити так, щоб не допустити спантеличення.

Comment: «Вважати кульбабу молочаєм… дуже поширена помилка» — я не думаю, що діалектні назви рослин/тварин (навіть коли вони збігаються з нормативними назвами інших рослин/тварин) є аж прямо **помилками**. По-моєму, це просто діалектні назви; я думаю, носії цих діалектів самі рослини не плутають, просто обидві рослини в них мають інші назви (або ж друга рослина просто не росте). Наприклад, я знаю, що в деяких місцях на заході України _гарбуз_ називають _динею_ — але це не означає, що вони не відрізняють гарбуз і диню, просто (нашу) диню вони або не вживають, або називають _солодкою динею_.

Comment: Я мав на увазі, що якщо на це дивитися з точки зору ботаніки - це помилка, бо все ж зовсім різні види рослин.

Comment: Але ж ніхто й не казав, що це один вид. Просто десь вид А називають молочаєм, а десь — вид Б називають молочаєм. ІМХО.

Comment: Ви праві, що, напевно, це не є надто груба помилка, однак в деяких випадках вона може призвести до непорозуміння, так само як і плутанина із динею та гарбузом (а в деяких регіонах так називають ще й кавун).

Comment: Ну, будь-які багатозначні слова (чи омоніми) можуть призвести до непорозуміння — але така вже природа людських мов (сама наявність додаткових значень, навіть _суто діалектних_, НМД, не є помилкою взагалі — але це, звісно, моя думка, **можу й помилятися**).